# Rake assets:precompile fails with: couldn't find file 'handlebars'

Tags: ember.js, rake, capistrano, sprockets, handlebars.js

Running the command during a capistrano deploy:

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile
```

returns

```
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'handlebars'
(in */app/assets/javascripts/application.js:22)
*/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:102:in `resolve'
*/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:142:in `require_asset'
*************
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:all
```

Gem ember-rails is in a global scope in my Gemfile and I am using handlebars-source (1.0.12), ember-rails (0.12.0), ember-source (1.0.0.rc6.2) in Rails 3.2.12 and ruby 1.9.3.
It's probably worth noting that this works in production, but not in staging deploys.

Also I have the following in my staging.rb, which appears to be the common issue.

```
config.ember.variant = :production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had added the line

```
config.ember.variant = :development
```

to a version that wasn't getting pushed to master. Added config.ember.variant = :development to the current version fixed this.